# Python - Making threading.thread not to wait for other threads to be done and to loop forever

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

So I am trying to figure out how threading more and more and I just made a simple script that looks like:

```
def test(name):
    while True:
          print(name)
          time.sleep(1)   



def main():
    try:
        random_names = []
        for names in [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('name.txt')]:
            random_names.append(names)

        threads = []
        for name in random_names:
            p = threading.Thread(target=test, args=(name,))
            threads.append(p)
            p.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard - Interrupted')
        sys.exit()
```

Basically I just created random text file that contains 100 names (Totally random) where my goal are that each thread will have a given thread running for it.

Now there is something I quite didn't get a grip off. I assume using thread.join is that when there is 100 threads running. Whenever 1 of them are done, it will wait basically until the rest are done if I am correct?

That takes me to question two: If you don't want it to happend and you basically just want to run the threading "for itself" meaning that whenever one of the thread is done, instead of waiting it should just continue to work again instead of waiting for the rest of threads to run?

And to my final question is, in which way would it possible to make it so the threads are running forever in that case? I assume that this code I am using now might be the fix now since I am using a **while True:** but is that a valid thing to do and will that mean that the **thread.join** will not even be touched if there is a while True running over and over in the **def test()?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread will run completely independent of the others (except as you create interdependencies). So if you create 100 threads, and the threads don't need any interaction from other threads, and one of them completes (*i.e.* exits by returning from its target function), the other 99 are unaffected and will just continue to run.

`thread.join` causes the calling thread to wait until the single target thread completes. In the absence of a timeout or some other outside factor, it will wait *forever* for the target thread to complete. The `join` is unaffected by any thread *other than* the target thread. In other words, if you're attempting to join thread 1, and thread 2 quits, that will not cause your `join` of thread 1 to complete any sooner or later.

In your code, your threads are all executing a `while True`, which means none of them will ever return from their target function and hence will never "complete". That means your main thread will hang on the first `thread.join` call forever. It's perfectly valid for your 100 threads to all execute forever if that is what you wish.

Likewise, it's fine for your main thread to call `join` like that. But of course, the main thread *could* go on to do other work as well. And if you don't expect the other threads to exit, there's no requirement for the main thread to call `join`. It could simply return (in effect, completing itself). The other threads and your program itself will happily continue to execute.

Or, you could even create 99 additional threads and have the main thread join in and call your `test` function as the 100th. (This would of course complicate the logic of your clean read-a-line-start-a-thread loop so I wouldn't actually recommend that.)

The way you have it now seems ideal. Because you *are* having the main thread wait in the `join` (even though the `join` will never complete), your `KeyboardInterrupt` exception handler remains in scope in the main thread so that your program terminates cleanly on Ctrl-C (`sys.exit` kills the entire process, and hence all the threads are terminated).

EDIT:
Apparently, `sys.exit` does *not* terminate the entire process -- only the thread in which it executes. You would need to use `os._exit` from the `KeyboardInterrupt` handler to exit cleanly (or stop each of the threads first).

Comment: You explained it very well! I understood everything of it and I thank you a lot of it! Just a smaller question - I assume going through the code I wrote before about the join. Since you explained that my code will never reach join at all. In that case I could basically just remove the join completely  and just run `p = threading.Thread(target=test, args=(name,)) - p.start()` in that case and it would work the same way in that case?

Comment: Yes. No need to save the thread object references in a list either if you never intend to `join` them.